# python Selenium - Github integration

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on selenium bot. I am trying to create a bot which signs in my account, types python, and follows all users. I am done with all process except following users. How can I do it?
error code:DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50247/devtools/browser/7fd47744-f8b0-4a95-a20f-b77cea8c0797
[18480:16164:0813/103442.394:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:34:42.394] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Sisteme ba­l² bir ayg²t al²■m²yor. (0x1F)
[18480:16164:0813/103442.498:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:34:42.498] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Sisteme ba­l² bir ayg²t al²■m²yor. (0x1F)

This is my code:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
url = "http://github.com"
driver.get(url)
password = "****"
username = "****"
    
searchInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a")
    
time.sleep(2)
searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
    
userName = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
passWord = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
signIn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login']/div[4]/form/div/input[12]")
userName.send_keys(username)
passWord.send_keys(password)
signIn.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
    
url1 = "https://github.com/search?q=python&type=users"
driver.get(url1)
time.sleep(3)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('submit-text.follow-text')
for buton in buttons :
    buton.click()
    
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Please add what error you are getting and what line the error is coming from.

Comment: My mistake to not including error message.i am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong locator, try changing that.

**Sample code :**

```
url1 = "https://github.com/search?q=python&type=users"
driver.get(url1)
time.sleep(3)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.btn.btn-sm")
for buton in buttons :
    buton.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```